# Prove that unit circle is a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I want to prove that unit cricle is a Lie grouop. $i.e$, want to show that the multiplication and inverse function is smooth.

The multiplication and inverse is given by 
\begin{align}
&m(e^{i\theta}, e^{i\phi}) = e^{i(\theta+\phi)}  \\
&i(e^{i\theta}) = e^{-i\theta}
\end{align}

i tried to find some proof for this but many textbook just state $\mathbb{S}^1$ is Lie group, and some textbook states multiplication and inverse as above

My naive guess is is introducing $f:\mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ such that $f(x) = e^{ix}$, and since $f$ is smooth, i think $m$ and $i$ are also smooth.

Is there something wrong with my interpretation?

Or is there any other ways to show that multiplication and inverse map is smooth?

Comment: Your guess is basically correct, though not really complete---essentially you are defining local coordinates on $\Bbb S^1$ to show that $m$ and $i$ are smooth.

Comment: Another option is to start with the $\Bbb C^*$ instead: In standard coordinates its multiplication and inverse maps are rational, hence smooth, so $(\Bbb C^*, \cdot)$ is a Lie group. Then, $\Bbb S^1 \subset \Bbb C^*$ is a closed subgroup and hence a Lie group.

Comment: @Travis, If i want to define a local coordinates on $\mathbb{S}^1$, you means like $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ such that $x^2+y^2=1$?  For this choice i can identify $z=x+iy$, then how can i prove $m$ and $i$ are smooth? For the Second comment what do you mean that maps are rational?  you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_mapping?

Comment: Since $\Bbb S^1$ is a $1$-manifold, a local coordinate chart is in particular a map $U \to \Bbb R$ on a subset $U \subset \Bbb S^1$. For this particular manifold there are a preferred class of charts, namely, the right inverses of the standard parameterization $\epsilon: x \mapsto e^{i x}$, and the coordinate determines by this charge is a "standard coordinate" in the sense of my previous post. By rational I just mean that the coordinate representations of $m$ and $i$ are themselves rational functions of the coordinate---in fact they are affine functions.

Comment: @Travis Willse , is this topology the same as the subspace topology of $S^1$ inherited from the plane?

Comment: @Travis Willse: the topology that makes $S^1$ into a Lie group agrees with the subspace topology of $S^1$ from the plane?

Comment: @MSIS Yes, the topology underlying the smooth structure on $S^1$ is the usual one, i.e., the subspace topology induced by the standard topology on the plane by the usual embedding map $S^1 \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2$. But n.b. that the topology doesn't alone determine the Lie group structure on $S^1$; rather the Lie group structure entails (or, if you like, determines) the topology.